# Get value insert in QR code without enter

Tags: javascript

Hello all please help me, i want to insert input value in qrcode without input anything.

```
         <input id="text" type="text" value="Please Enter Your NRIC or Work 
         Permit" style="Width:20%"/ onblur='generateBarCode();'> 

        <img id='barcode' src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?
        data=HelloWorld&amp;size=100x100" alt="" title="HELLO" width="50" 
        height="50" />

           <script type="text/javascript">
              function generateBarCode() 
              {
                 var nric = $('#text').val();
                 var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + 
                 nric + '&amp;size=50x50';
                 $('#barcode').attr('src', url);
              }
         </script>
```

Please check this fiddle link:-

https://jsfiddle.net/v274z2oc/

Comment: if you don't want to input anything, what value do you expect?

Comment: DON'T WRITE IN ALL CAPS (please)

Comment: means if already enter in value "yes" then insert yes value. i fetch data from php. That's why i want this

Comment: Ok @FedericoklezCulloca sorry for inconvenience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add event listener on `window.onload` for this to work. See below

```js
window.onload = generateBarCode;
function generateBarCode() {
  var nric = $('#text').val();
  var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + nric + '&amp;size=50x50';
  $('#barcode').attr('src', url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text" value="Please Enter Your NRIC or Work Permit" style="Width:20%" / onblur='generateBarCode();'>

<img id='barcode' src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&amp;size=100x100" alt="" title="HELLO" width="50" height="50" />
```

Comment: You just had to add `window.onload` which will fire on page load.